# Get range from a cell formatted as (A1:A15)

Tags: vba, excel, range, cells

It might be a simple question but I couldn't find an answer yet
I have a cell which contains cells range as a text at the format of A1:A15.
I am trying to write a function to receive the actual range of the cells (A1:A15) but it only gives me the address at which the actual cell is (B4).

how can I get the range itself and not the address of the cell?

the function is:

```
Function IsSick(ByVal Arr As Range) As Integer
   Dim i, k As Integer
   k = 0
   Arr.Select
   For i = 2 To Arr.Count
       If Arr(i) >= 37 Then k = k + 1
   Next i
   IsSick = k
End Function
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Function IsSick(ArrAdr As Range) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim arr As Range
    Set arr = Range(ArrAdr.Value)
    k = 0
    For i = 2 To arr.Count
        If arr(i) >= 37 Then k = k + 1
    Next i
    IsSick = k
End Function
```

or better:

```
Function IsSick(ArrAdr As Range) As Integer
    IsSick = Application.CountIf(Range(ArrAdr.Value), ">=37")
End Function
```

Also note that when you're using `Dim i, k As Integer`, only `k` has type `Integer`, while `i` is `Variant`. So, you should use `Dim i As Integer, k As Integer` instead.

And read: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Thank you for response, the issue is that the function **has** to get range and not string, beside that thank you